# Почему оптимизация miui мешает установке apk?

Tags: android, отладка

Написал небольшое приложение под андроид. На эмуляторе (андроид 6 и андроид 9) работает нормально. Подписанный apk создало. Решил проверить на физическом устройстве (xiaomi redmi 4x, версия андроид 6.0.1 MMB29M, версия MIUI MIUI Global 8.2 Стабильная 8.2.9.0(MAMMIEA). Apk не ставится. Через android studio (adb драйвера есть, отладка по usb настроена) тоже выдает ошибку. Отключил в опциях разработчиков оптимизацию miui. Установилось. Вопрос: что нужно сделать, чтобы оптимизация miui не мешала приложению?

тексты ошибок:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.facebook.katana/app_qpl/qpl_sampling_config.tmp: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
        at X.1nX.run(:119111)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
        at X.1kv.run(:117294)
        at X.0vZ.run(:177909)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at X.1l8.run(:117313)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76) 
        at X.1nX.run(:119111) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423) 
        at X.1kv.run(:117294) 
        at X.0vZ.run(:177909) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
        at X.1l8.run(:117313) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 

01-10 14:33:05.461 3989-8680/? E/Finsky: [114] com.google.android.finsky.setup.ao.a(92): Error prefetching preloads, using account=null, preloads=NULL, preloadGroups=NULL
    com.google.android.finsky.setup.fetchers.RawDocumentsFetchException[reason=pai_config, account=[zELQ8-zDIhn5ynjENzButEFKIp0]]
        at com.google.android.finsky.setup.ao.a(SourceFile:47)
        at com.google.android.finsky.setup.ap.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)


01-10 14:33:08.385 3989-8680/? E/Finsky: [114] com.google.android.finsky.setup.ao.a(92): Error prefetching preloads, using account=null, preloads=NULL, preloadGroups=NULL
    com.google.android.finsky.setup.fetchers.RawDocumentsFetchException[reason=pai_config, account=[zELQ8-zDIhn5ynjENzButEFKIp0]]
        at com.google.android.finsky.setup.ao.a(SourceFile:47)
        at com.google.android.finsky.setup.ap.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Выдача вкладки run:

```
01/10 14:32:58: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-apk\debug\app-debug.apk 
$ adb shell pm uninstall roninapps.wlcallsuppressor
$ adb install-multiple -r -t E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk E:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\WLCallSuppressor\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-apk\debug\app-debug.apk 
$ adb shell pm uninstall roninapps.wlcallsuppressor
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
Error while Installing APKs
```

Такая выдача и при установке, и при переустановке

Comment: а включили "можно устанавливать apk из непроверенных источников"? там же в настройках

Comment: Да. Фича в том, что не работает только при включенной оптимизации => дело, скорее всего, в оптимизации.

Comment: Ошибку-то процитируйте...

Comment: Добавил все ошибки, которые могут быть связаны с этим.